# What does "Uncaught (in promise) Object" mean?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, promise

I have such an error. How it can be corrected and debugged. I want the code to stop when there is a problem.
My code

```
export function postRequestOtpCode(phone: string, token: string): CancellableAxiosPromise {
  axios.defaults.baseURL = ARGO_ENV.API_APPLICATION_URL;
  return API.post('/otp/request-otp-code', { phone: `7${getCleanPhoneNumber(phone)}`, token }, {});
}


async function requestOtpCode(phone: string, captchaToken?) {
  try {
    clearTimer();
    setOtpLoading(true);
    const res = await postRequestOtpCode(phone, captchaToken);
    setOtpState(OTPstate.SHOW);
    startTimer();
    return res;
  } catch (err) {
    throw handleError(err);
  } finally {
    setOtpLoading(false);
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: It means  there is an Error thrown by a promise (async function is promise under the hood) that has not been caught. You caught the error, but throw it again in `throw handleError(err);`. The error thrown by `throw handleError(err);` has to be caught again in the caller.

Comment: Is it ok that `postRequestOtpCode` is not async?

Comment: @illiachill Yes as the function returns a `Promise`.  You don't mark `async` if the function returns a `Promise`, otherwise you will have to await twice. You only mark `async` when the function is returning a value, that value will be the resolve value of the under the hood `Promise`.

Comment: @RickyMo Do you mean like this?

export function postRequestOtpCode(phone: string, token: string): {
  axios.defaults.baseURL = ARGO_ENV.API_APPLICATION_URL;
  const x = API.post('/otp/request-otp-code', { phone: `7${getCleanPhoneNumber(phone)}`, token }, {});
x.catch(e => {throw new Error(e)})
retrun x
}

Answer (score 0):

`requestOtpCode` return a promise because it is an async function.

You are doing good by "try cathing" the axios call, but you have an `uncaught Error` because of the `throw` you added.

Remove the throw in the catch since it's redundant, the catch is here to handle the possible error of the axios call and do something with it like logging or render a user readable error report.

If you want to stop the code you can return.

Here is an [article](https://javascript.info/try-catch) for a more detailed explanation of try...catch in js

Comment: It looks like the OP is using `handleError` to process the caught error, so the `throw` wouldn't be redundant.

Comment: Your right, it would not be redundant if he wanted to throw the error to the function above requestOtpCode? I feel like the `uncaught Error` come from the `handleError` function who might return a promise ?

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
requestOtpCode(phone, captcha)
  .catch(e => throw new Error()) // here blocked after Error
  .then(() => setOtpState(OTPstate.SHOW))
```